# Wrap C++ contains external C

Tags: c++

I implemented my C++ code normally. After I finished, I started to decide to implement wrapper to be able to access my Core in C#. But once I included my project and on building I got many error messages with

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C"....

Example:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long **thiscall CPreview::CheckDeviceLost(struct _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR *,int *)" (?CheckDeviceLost@CPreview@@$$FQAEJPAU_DEV_BROADCAST_HDR@@PAH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnDeviceChange(struct HWND** *,struct _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR *)" (?OnDeviceChange@@$$FYAXPAUHWND__@@PAU_DEV_BROADCAST_HDR@@@Z) C:\Users\mariame\Desktop\WrapperCameraModule\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper.obj    camera_module_wrapper

or

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00007E) "extern "C"

Example:

> Error 32  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0000B5) "extern "C" long __stdcall DispatchMessageW(struct tagMSG const *)" (?DispatchMessageW@@$$J14YGJPBUtagMSG@@@Z) referenced in function "extern "C" long __cdecl DispatchMessage(struct tagMSG const *)" (?DispatchMessage@@$$J0YAJPBUtagMSG@@@Z)  C:\Users\mariame\Desktop\WrapperCameraModule\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper.obj    camera_module_wrapper

I have not used any extern "C" in my code. They are in the included function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <Dbt.h>
#include <ks.h>
#include <ksmedia.h>
```

What shall I do I need to implement the wrapper

Comment: Please post the offending line.

Comment: I got many error not only one example this:"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall EnableWindow(struct HWND__ *,int)" (?EnableWindow@@$$J18YGHPAUHWND__@@H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnInitDialog(struct HWND__ *,class Devices *)" (?OnInitDialog@@$$FYAXPAUHWND__@@PAVDevices@@@Z) C:\Users\mariame\Desktop\WrapperCameraModule\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper\camera_module_wrapper.obj camera_module_wrapper"

Comment: @tulipe Post the errors with your question. Also post the part of your code you suspect is causing this with an explanation of what it does.

Comment: they are around 67 error messages  which one shall I select

Comment: Post the parts of your code which you think is causing these errors ( don't forget  indentations ).

Comment: @ArunA.S I added the included libraries caused the problem

Comment: I don't have their source code they are MF(Media Foundation) lib

Comment: If this is not a Unicode project, try changing the Configuration/General/Character Set to MBCS.

Comment: @Mgetz how to add and why is that?

Comment: @tulipe it seems you have more than one problem because `user32.lib` **IS** included by default into the linked libraries by default. I don't think we have a good idea of what's going on here. Most likely you're missing a linker dependency. The other option is you have unimplemented functionality.

Comment: @Mgetz I have added the required dependencies and I still have errors,less too much but still here